# How to solve visual problems with the dash home?

Tags: graphics, unity-dash

Every time I try to use Dash Home I get this glitchy visual fireworks display with random colors and text missing. This is the screen-shoot:

[image: visual_error_opening_dash]

Is this in relation to how my graphics driver is unknown? Other than this visuals for everything else works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I had the same problem, and solved it by switching graphics drivers.

Go to System Settings -> Software Sources -> Additional Drivers, and select a different driver.